# To find $\lim_{x\to\infty}(e^{-10x}\cdot \int f(x)e^{10x} dx)$

Tags: integration, limits

Given that $f(x)$ is a continuous function such that $\lim_{x\to \infty}f(x)=1$.
I have to find $\lim_{x\to\infty}(e^{-10x}\cdot \int [f(x)e^{10x}] dx)$.
I simply took $f(x)=1$ and got the answer as $0.1$ which is matching with the given answer.
But I am not sure why this should be true for any such function $f$.
I think there's might some way to interchange limit and integration but not sure how.

Edit : The original question is this.
Consider the differential equation $\frac{dy}{dx}+10y=f(x), x>0$, where $f(x)$ is a continuous function such that $\lim_{x\to \infty}f(x)=1$.
Then the value of $\lim_{x\to \infty}y(x)$ is ?
This was the original question whose solution using some integrating factor technique is 
$y\cdot e^{10x}=\int f(x)\cdot e^{10x}+C$.
I was confused about last step of taking $\lim_{x\to\infty}y(x)$, so I asked only that part.

Comment: What do u mean by this integral? What are the limits?

Comment: Is the ans $\frac{1}{10}$?

Comment: @insipidintegrator Yes

Comment: L-hopital would do it..

Comment: How to take derivative of term involving integral?

Comment: I don't think this question has sense. Maybe you want to solve $\lim_{x\to\infty}(e^{-10x}\cdot \int_0^x [f(t)e^{10t}] dt)$?

Comment: @Believer yes, L’HÔPITAL

Comment: $\dfrac {d(\int f(x).e^{10x} dx)} {dx}= f(x).e^{10x}$, for the sake of solving this question otherwise it doesn't make much sense without the limits

Comment: If the integration range contains a left neighbourhood of $+\infty$ and $f(x)\to 1$ as $x\to +\infty$, the integral is divergent and the limit makes no sense.

Comment: It makes sense to consider $$ \lim_{x\to +\infty} e^{-10 x}\int_{0}^{x} f(t) e^{10 t}\,dt,$$ but that's a different question.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio I think I should post the original question. I will edit my question soon.

Comment: Edited to original question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Starting with
$$ y' + 10y = f(x) $$
it is reasonable to introduce $g(x) = y(x) e^{10x}$, in order to write the identity above as
$$ g'(x) = f(x) e^{10 x}, $$
$$ g(x) = g(a)+ \int_{a}^{x} f(t) e^{10 t}\,dt $$
for an arbitrary $a\in\mathbb{R}^+$. This gives
$$ y(x) = y(a) e^{10a-10 x}+e^{-10 x}\int_{a}^{x} f(t) e^{10 t}\,dt $$
and $\lim_{x \to +\infty} y(x)=\frac{1}{10}$ by De l'Hospital.

Comment: sir how you got the idea to came up with $g(x)=y(x)e^{10x}$?

Comment: @Believer: from the solution of the homogeneous differential equation $y'+10y=0$.

Comment: it's solution is $y(x)=e^{-10x}$.. then why or how you thought of taking $g(x)=y(x)e^{10x}$.. still kind of mysterious to me

Comment: Since the solution of the homogeneous equation is $e^{-10 x}$, by considering $y(x)e^{10 x}$ we are reasonably dealing with an almost constant function, that is the point.

Answer (score 1):

you can use L'Hopital's rule provided that:
$$\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)e^{10x}\to\infty$$
and as such there is the restriction that:
$$O(f(x))>O(e^{-10x})$$
This provides you with:
$$L=\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{f(x)}{10}$$
However for a general function $f$ that does not meet these conditions this method cannot be applied